# Duplicate value adding in array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a object like this :

```
totalProduct = [{name: "A", string: "Hello"}, {name: "A", string: "Hello"}, {name: "B", string: "Hey"}];
```

I calculate the total of the same name. So far everything is fine, I did this :

```
let counts = {};
for (const i in totalProduct) {
  const nameObject = totalProduct[i].name;
  const stringObject = totalProduct[i].string;

  counts[nameObject] = (counts[nameObject]||0) + 1;
}
```

The output is this :

```
{A:2, B:1}
```

BUT, i would like to have this output (Put the object value inside of an array with a string), but i don't know how to do this :(

```
{A:[2, 'Hello'], B:[1, 'Hey']}
```

I'have tried to do this but it's not working :

```
let counts = {};
for (const i in totalProduct) {
  const nameObject = totalProduct[i].name;
  const stringObject = totalProduct[i].string;

  counts[nameObject] = [(counts[nameObject]||0) + 1, stringObject];
}
```

Comment: From where these string objects came from?

Comment: That is, the `Hello` and `Hey`, where do they originate?

Comment: The Hello and Hey come from `const stringObject = totalProduct[i].string;`

Comment: `totalProduct = [{name: "A"}, {name: "A"}, {name: "B"}];` this does not have a property `string`

Comment: for every object with value `A` on its `name` property, they will also have the same `string` value? Could there be `{ name : 'A', string: 'Hello' }` and `{ name : 'A', string: 'Hey' }` ?

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry I forgot that, I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `counts[nameObject]` to an array of two elements

```js
const totalProduct = [{name: "A", string: "Hello"}, {name: "A", string: "Hello"}, {name: "B", string: "Hey"}];

let counts = {};
for (const i in totalProduct) {
  const nameObject = totalProduct[i].name;
  const stringObject = totalProduct[i].string;
  const prevObj = counts[nameObject]
  counts[nameObject] = [(prevObj ? prevObj[0] : 0) + 1, stringObject];
}
console.log(counts);
```

Answer (score 1):

When iterating over the array, instead of putting just the *count* as the value in the object, put the `[number, string]` array (like your desired object) onto the object. On each iteration, create the array inside the object if the property doesn't exist yet, and then increment the `[0]`th item in the array regardless:

```js
const arr = [{name: "A", string: 'Hello'}, {name: "A", string: 'Hello'}, {name: "B", string: 'Hey'}];

const obj = {};
for (const { name, string } of arr) {
  if (!obj[name]) obj[name] = [0, string];
  obj[name][0]++;
}
console.log(obj);
```